# Including "siesta" in Schema.org OpeningHoursSpecification in JSON-LD

Tags: time, schema.org, json-ld

I'm using Schema.org `OpeningHoursSpecification` in JSON-LD in such a way:

```json
[{"@type":"OpeningHoursSpecification","dayOfWeek": ["Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday"],"open":"08:00","closes":"20:00"},{"@type":"OpeningHoursSpecification","dayOfWeek":["Saturday"],"open":"08:00","closes":"14:00"},{"@type":"OpeningHoursSpecification","dayOfWeek":["Sunday"],"open":"00:00","closes":"00:00"}]
```

I couldn't find any example for adapting this specification to include "siesta" - a situation when a place operates e.g. from 8AM to 1PM and from 3PM to 8PM.

Comment: Note that `dayOfWeek` expects a [`DayOfWeek`](http://schema.org/DayOfWeek) value (which is an enumeration). So the value is not a string (`Monday`), but a URI (`http://schema.org/Monday`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDITED PER @UNOR**

This might get you started:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "Service",
    "url": "http://www.example.com/",
    "hoursAvailable": [{
        "@type": "OpeningHoursSpecification",
        "opens": "08:00",
        "closes": "13:00",
        "dayOfWeek": [{
            "@type": "DayOfWeek",
            "@id": "http://schema.org/Monday",
            "name": "Monday"
        },
        {
            "@type": "DayOfWeek",
            "@id": "http://schema.org/Tuesday",
            "name": "Tuesday"
        },
        {
            "@type": "DayOfWeek",
            "@id": "http://schema.org/Wednesday",
            "name": "Wednesday"
        },
        {
            "@type": "DayOfWeek",
            "@id": "http://schema.org/Thursday",
            "name": "Thursday"
        },
        {
            "@type": "DayOfWeek",
            "@id": "http://schema.org/Friday",
            "name": "Friday"
        }]
    },
    {
        "@type": "OpeningHoursSpecification",
        "opens": "15:00",
        "closes": "20:00",
        "dayOfWeek": [{
            "@type": "DayOfWeek",
            "@id": "http://schema.org/Monday",
            "name": "Monday"
        },
        {
            "@type": "DayOfWeek",
            "@id": "http://schema.org/Tuesday",
            "name": "Tuesday"
        },
        {
            "@type": "DayOfWeek",
            "@id": "http://schema.org/Wednesday",
            "name": "Wednesday"
        },
        {
            "@type": "DayOfWeek",
            "@id": "http://schema.org/Thursday",
            "name": "Thursday"
        },
        {
            "@type": "DayOfWeek",
            "@id": "http://schema.org/Friday",
            "name": "Friday"
        }]
    }]
}
</script>
```

You can embellish with a more precise type of `@Service` and add time zone information.

Comment: It seems that "Mo,Tu,We,Th,Fr 9:00-12:30  14:00-17:30" is a valid value for "OpeningHours". This makes the code easier to manage. Tested with Google Structured Data Validator.

Comment: it is easier to manage, but you will not be able to achieve reuse without using `@id`. while literals are easier for a human to read, they present problems for machine-reading. Caveat emptor.