# How to write valid opening hours with lunch break in schema.org with JSON-LD

Tags: schema.org, json-ld

I was reading all posts around this topic here but couldn't find a solution.

I'm building a page for a business that has the following opening hours:

**Monday-Friday 07:00 - 12:00 and 13:00 - 17:00** (1 hour lunch break)

I can't find a way to write this as valid JSON-LD for my schema.org markup. Google's rich results test tool is not accepting my ideas and on schema.org documentation I cannot find any examples for a case like that.

The standard valid code **without the lunch break** looks like this:

```
"openingHoursSpecification": {
    "@type": "OpeningHoursSpecification",
    "dayOfWeek": [
      "Monday",
      "Tuesday",
      "Wednesday",
      "Thursday",
      "Friday"
    ],
    "opens": "07:00",
    "closes": "17:00"
  },
```

The code that **I would like to have** there is something like this, but I can't validate it and I can't find any examples that show how it's done.

```
"openingHoursSpecification": {
    "@type": "OpeningHoursSpecification",
    "dayOfWeek": [
      "Monday",
      "Tuesday",
      "Wednesday",
      "Thursday",
      "Friday"
    ],
    "opens": "07:00",
    "closes": "12:00",
    "opens": "13:00",
    "closes": "17:00"
  },
```

Comment: start with this and then ask more specific question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38870645/including-siesta-in-schema-org-openinghoursspecification-in-json-ld/38885821#38885821

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution using `hoursAvailable` in these older posts seems to be working. Tested with Google's testing tool:

Original Post: [Including "siesta" in Schema.org OpeningHoursSpecification in JSON-LD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38870645/including-siesta-in-schema-org-openinghoursspecification-in-json-ld/38885821#38885821)

Code from the original post:

```
{
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "Service",
    "url": "http://www.example.com/",
    "hoursAvailable": [{
        "@type": "OpeningHoursSpecification",
        "opens": "08:00",
        "closes": "13:00",
        "dayOfWeek": [{
            "@type": "DayOfWeek",
            "@id": "http://schema.org/Monday",
            "name": "Monday"
        },
        {
            "@type": "DayOfWeek",
            "@id": "http://schema.org/Tuesday",
            "name": "Tuesday"
        },
        {
            "@type": "DayOfWeek",
            "@id": "http://schema.org/Wednesday",
            "name": "Wednesday"
        },
        {
            "@type": "DayOfWeek",
            "@id": "http://schema.org/Thursday",
            "name": "Thursday"
        },
        {
            "@type": "DayOfWeek",
            "@id": "http://schema.org/Friday",
            "name": "Friday"
        }]
    },
    {
        "@type": "OpeningHoursSpecification",
        "opens": "15:00",
        "closes": "20:00",
        "dayOfWeek": [{
            "@type": "DayOfWeek",
            "@id": "http://schema.org/Monday",
            "name": "Monday"
        },
        {
            "@type": "DayOfWeek",
            "@id": "http://schema.org/Tuesday",
            "name": "Tuesday"
        },
        {
            "@type": "DayOfWeek",
            "@id": "http://schema.org/Wednesday",
            "name": "Wednesday"
        },
        {
            "@type": "DayOfWeek",
            "@id": "http://schema.org/Thursday",
            "name": "Thursday"
        },
        {
            "@type": "DayOfWeek",
            "@id": "http://schema.org/Friday",
            "name": "Friday"
        }]
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Schema has the property **[specialOpeningHoursSpecification](https://schema.org/specialOpeningHoursSpecification)** that:

> The special opening hours of a certain place. Use this to explicitly
> override general opening hours brought in scope by
> *openingHoursSpecification* or *openingHours*.

My suggestion for markup for your lunch:

```js
<script type="application/ld+json">
  {
"@context":"https://schema.org",
  "@type":"Restaurant",
    "name":"GreatFood",
      "openingHoursSpecification":{
        "@type":"OpeningHoursSpecification",
          "dayOfWeek":[
            "Monday",
            "Tuesday",
            "Wednesday",
            "Thursday",
            "Friday"
          ],
            "opens":"07:00",
              "closes":"17:00"
      },
        "specialOpeningHoursSpecification":{
          "@type":"OpeningHoursSpecification",
            "dayOfWeek":[
              "Monday",
              "Tuesday",
              "Wednesday",
              "Thursday",
              "Friday"
            ],
              "closes": "12:00",
                "opens": "13:00"
        }
  }
</script>
```

I have not been able to find official examples for this property. I am confused by the following saying in the documentation about type **[OpeningHoursSpecification](https://schema.org/OpeningHoursSpecification)**:

> If the value for the closes property is less than the value for the
> opens property then the hour range is assumed to span over the next
> day.

The documentation of Schema does not explicitly indicate how this is accounted for the property *openingHoursSpecification*. Therefore, I do not know how it will be understood by search engines. Perhaps the best solution is to create an experiment and analyze the result.

Comment: Thanks for the idea! That's technically valid and as you point out it must be done as an experiment to see how search engine understands this. I'll just try it. I find it odd though that the standard openingHoursSpecification has no official option for segmented opening hours... In my view that's a pretty standard case for smaller businesses in smaller cities... But maybe that's more of a European thing and in the US businesses never have lunch breaks? :)